# Getting path of originally executed script in python?

Tags: python

I have the following working directory from which I am running ankiAdd.py - in this script at one point i'm accessing the 'internal API' of another python program elsewhere on my hard drive in order to use some of those functions. I would like to get the working directory where 'ankiAdd.py' is stored however I kept retrieving another directory.

[image: Working directory]

The following snippet is a function within my ankiAdd.py script. Collection is imported from another directory on my hard drive in which another program Anki is installed. I'd like the file_pattern variable to give the directory of this script and not the directory of cpath, which is currently happening.

```
sys.path.append("C:/Users/Shaun/Documents/Personal_Projects/ankiExperiment/anki-scripting/anki")
from anki.storage import Collection
PROFILE_HOME = os.path.expanduser("C:/Users/Shaun/Desktop/User 1")
cpath = os.path.join(PROFILE_HOME, "collection.anki2")

@eel.expose
def callLoad():
    col = Collection(cpath, log=True)
    json_pattern = "word_data.json"
    file_pattern = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),json_pattern)
    load(col,file_pattern)
```

I've tried numerous things like os.getcwd() and os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**)) however I kept ending up retrieving C:\Users\User\Desktop\User 1\collection.media which is the location of cpath. How can I get the directory of ankiAdd.py which is the script which was originally run?

edit:

```
def callLoad():
    col = Collection(cpath, log=True)
    json_pattern = "word_data.json"
    print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    file_pattern = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),json_pattern)
    #load(col,file_pattern)

if __name__ == '__main__':
callLoad()
```

if I run this code, the directory returned is C:\Users\Shaun\Desktop\User 1\collection.media which is the directory set by this at the top of my file:

```
PROFILE_HOME = os.path.expanduser("C:/Users/Shaun/Desktop/User 1")
```

I am running the script from

[image: workspace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to get the location of a file or module you're importing, and keep getting the location of the file or module that's *doing* the import. This can be resolved!

Anything you import will have a `__file__` attribute. If you had, for instance,

```
import anki

print(anki.__file__)
```

you would get the location of the `anki` module's `__init__.py` file (or if `anki` is just a Python file, you'd get the location of the file itself).

Comment: I'm actually trying to get the location of the .py script in my working directory and using __ file __ I'm getting back this path which I set as a variable PROFILE_HOME = os.path.expanduser("C:/Users/Shaun/Desktop/User 1"). I'd like to get the location of the file from which I call import anki

Answer (score 0):

**file** returns the location of the script in execution. You can try this.

```
print(__file__)
```

Comment: If I call a function callLoad() from  if __name__ == '__main__' where I have print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))) inside of that function the directory that is returned is not the directory of the .py script that I am running. (Please see my edit)

Comment: Can you try this in place of __file__ and share me the output path ?
" print(sys.argv[0]) "

Note: Please do import "sys" and "os" packages.

Comment: Thank you. sys and os are both imported. print(sys.argv[0]) in that function gives back "ankAdd.py" - is there a way to display the full path?